# How to save a UISwitch state (on or off) when opening an app? (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, save, tableview, uiswitch

I set up a view controller that pops up modally from my initial view controller and set up a table view in this new view controller that has each cell filled in with a string from an array (allFactions) that I created. Each cell in this table view also has a switch attached to it.

I set each switch up to append/remove from the allFactions array whether on or off but I can't seem to:
1. Permanently modify the array (the array goes back to default when I return to the initial view controller).
2. Save the state of the UISwitch in each cell to stay either on or off when reentering the app.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return utilities.allFactions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Writes a new faction on every line of the table
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = utilities.allFactions[indexPath.row]

    // Creates a switch that can be toggle "on" or "off"
    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    mySwitch.isOn = true

    // Adds the switch to the right side of the cell
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

    return cell

}

@objc func didChangeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if sender.isOn {
        // Append selected faction to myFactions
        addFaction(utilities.allFactions[sender.tag])
        } else {
        // Remove selected faction from myFactions
        removeFaction(utilities.allFactions[sender.tag])
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Coredata or UserDefaults with your app to store data, or else data in your app will just be reset each time it is opened, or each time a view is dissmissed. You can create a UserDefaults to store your array in and access your array through the UserDefaults each time you need it.

**To Store your array in UserDefaults**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["your array here"], forKey: "set a key to access your array here")
```

**To Access your array**

```
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "the key you set when setting the array")
```

You can also do something similar to this for storing the state of your switches.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `[Bool]` to your class with the array count of `utilities.allFactions.count` and you can store this array in `UserDefaults`. And retrieve it when you load the tableView. Here's the code you need:

```
var switchStates = [Bool]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if switchStates.isEmpty {
        switchStates = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "switchStates") as? [Bool] ?? []
    }
    if switchStates.isEmpty {
        switchStates = (0..<utilities.allFactions.count).map { $0 == $0 }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(switchStates, forKey: "switchStates")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And in `cellForRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // ...
    mySwitch.isOn = switchStates[indexPath.row]
    // ...
}
```

In `didChangeSwitch`:

```
@objc func didChangeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    switchStates[sender.tag].toggle()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(switchStates, forKey: "switchStates")
    //...
}
```

Comment: I added that code to my class, but when I exited the view controller and returned to it, all of the switches were in the "on" mode. I used the print function to check if the append/remove functions had been saved to the array, but everything just went back to default.

Comment: You need to toggle the value corresponding to indexPath.row inside your toggle action. and save it.

Comment: I've added `didChangeSwitch` part too, check it.

Comment: Awesome! The Switch stays off! The only issue I'm running into now is that it's not saving the state of my array. When I turn the switch off, I'm removing the string from my array, but when I reenter the VC the string that was supposed to be removed is still in the array even though the switch is set to "off".

Comment: This seems to be a follow-up question. Why don't you try to figure this out step by step on your own? If you find it too difficult ask another question with the complete details on SO and comment the link here I'll take a look and help you figure out where you're going wrong.